# Keras: Incompatibility between Theano and Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, theano, keras

please note: This question exists as an [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4273) on github, too.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to implement a custom layer in Keras: A GRU layer which computes its gates via a convolution.
The code works, but only with the Theano backend.

On github, I got the tip to switch the "image-layout" to "tf" in keras.json.
In fact, I had hardcoded the "th" image layout, so I had to fix a few problems with my code.
Now it supports both "th" and "tf" layout.
The model was also adapted: Now I've got two models, one for "th" and one for "tf".

This is a complete rewrite of the question. The problem is the same, but the code is new.

With theano as backend, both image layouts run fine. The network is able to learn from data, the new layer seems to work. I'm fairly sure that my implementation of both the "th" and "tf" layout are correct.
But when I switch to tensorflow, it invariably crashes. The layout doesn't seem to have an effect.

There is one trick in the code: The GRU is using a convolution to calculate its gates. But that convolution is not included in the layer. I simply assume that every time you use this layer, there is a 2D convolution before it, which produces 3 output features (one for each gate).
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras import initializations, activations
from keras.engine import InputSpec
from keras.layers.recurrent import Recurrent


# copied from the keras github source. removed lots of unnecessary (for me) code

# assuming a 2D Convolution was run by hand before this layer.
# please note that this has no variables of its own.
# TODO: incorporate the 2D Convolution into this layer

class CGRU(Recurrent):
    def __init__(self,
                 init='glorot_uniform', inner_init='orthogonal',
                 activation='tanh', inner_activation='hard_sigmoid', **kwargs):

        self.init = initializations.get(init)
        self.inner_init = initializations.get(inner_init)
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.inner_activation = activations.get(inner_activation)

        self.dim_ordering = K.image_dim_ordering()
        assert self.dim_ordering in {'tf', 'th'}, '`dim_ordering` must be in {"tf", "th"}.'

        # removing the regularizers and the dropout

        super(CGRU, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # this seems necessary in order to accept 5 input dimensions
        # (samples, timesteps, features, x, y)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=5)]

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(shape=input_shape)]

        if self.dim_ordering == "th":
            nb_features = input_shape[2]
            x_dim = input_shape[3]
            y_dim = input_shape[4]

            # the input_dim was broken and didn't cause any problems. I'm commenting it out to see
            # whether it is really necessary
            # self.input_dim = (3,x_dim, y_dim)

            # moved here from the constructor. Curiously it seems like batch_size has been removed from here.
            # I also don't understand why I don't need to specify the time_sequence if there is the flag
            # output_sequence is set to True
            # TODO: debug where this is used
            self.output_dim = [1, x_dim, y_dim]

        elif self.dim_ordering == "tf":
            nb_features = input_shape[4]
            x_dim = input_shape[2]
            y_dim = input_shape[3]

            # see above
            # self.input_dim = (x_dim, y_dim, 3)

            # see above
            self.output_dim = [x_dim, y_dim, 1]

        assert (nb_features == 3, "the CGRU expects 3 input features")

        if self.stateful:
            self.reset_states()
        else:
            # initial states: all-zero tensor of shape (output_dim)
            self.states = [None]

    def reset_states(self):

        assert self.stateful, 'Layer must be stateful.'
        input_shape = self.input_spec[0].shape
        if not input_shape[0]:
            raise Exception('If a RNN is stateful, a complete ' +
                            'input_shape must be provided (including batch size).')

        if self.dim_ordering == "th":
            nb_features = input_shape[2]
            x_dim = input_shape[3]
            y_dim = input_shape[4]

        elif self.dim_ordering == "tf":
            nb_features = input_shape[4]
            x_dim = input_shape[2]
            y_dim = input_shape[3]

        if hasattr(self, 'states'):
            K.set_value(self.states[0],
                        np.zeros((input_shape[0], x_dim, y_dim)))
        else:
            self.states = [K.zeros((input_shape[0], x_dim, y_dim))]

    def preprocess_input(self, x):
        # TODO: if at some point, this layer does calculations, revisit and optimise this code
        return x

    def step(self, x, states):
        h_tm1 = states[0]  # previous memory

        # usually here would be matrix multiplications for the different gates
        # I assume that a convolution before this layer has prepared 3 features per coordinate
        # I'll simply use those 3 features
        # in fact: this layer doesn't have any trainable weights

        # TODO: is an if else problematic wrt performance.
        # TODO: since I'm currently trying to get the layer to work with tensorflow, I'll now hardcode for tf
        if self.dim_ordering == "th":
            z = self.inner_activation(x[:, 0, :, :])
            r = self.inner_activation(x[:, 1, :, :])
            hh = self.activation(x[:, 2, :, :])
        else:  # self.dim_ordering == "th":
            z = self.inner_activation(x[:, :, :, 0])
            r = self.inner_activation(x[:, :, :, 1])
            hh = self.activation(x[:, :, :, 2])

        h = z * h_tm1 + (1 - z) * hh
        return h, [h]

    def get_initial_states(self, x):
        initial_state = K.zeros_like(x)  # (samples, timesteps, input_dim)
        # input_dim = (3, x_dim, y_dim) for th
        # input_dim = (x_dim, y_dim, 3) for tf
        # please note: the number of features is expected to be 3, one feature for each gate

        if self.dim_ordering == "th":
            initial_state = K.sum(initial_state, axis=(1, 2))  # (samples, x_dim, y_dim)
        else:  # "tf"
            initial_state = K.sum(initial_state, axis=(1, -1))  # (samples, x_dim, y_dim)

        return [initial_state]

    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
        if self.return_sequences:
            return tuple([input_shape[0], input_shape[1]] + self.output_dim)
        else:
            return tuple([input_shape[0]] + self.output_dim)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'output_dim': self.output_dim,
                  'init': self.init.__name__,
                  'inner_init': self.inner_init.__name__,
                  'activation': self.activation.__name__,
                  'inner_activation': self.inner_activation.__name__}

        # removed the various regularizers and dropouts.
        # surely this isn't needed if not present ?
        base_config = super(CGRU, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Sorry to flood you with so much code, I've tried to comment and format it as well as possible.

Here's the setup, this is how I use the code:

```
if K.image_dim_ordering()=="tf":
    # this is the actual input, fed to the network
    inputs = Input((40, 40, 40, 1))

    # now reshape to a sequence
    #reshaped = Reshape((40, 1, 40, 40))(inputs)

    # now create a model like uNet which is fed the time-distributed data
    # this model will perform a segmentation on a 2D slice of data.

    conv_inputs = Input((40, 40, 1))
    base_filters_size = 16
    conv1 = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv_inputs)
    #conv1 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv1)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv1)
    #conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv1)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(3, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv1)
    convmodel = Model(input=conv_inputs, output=conv1)

    convmodel.summary()

    #apply the segmentation to each layer
    time_dist=TimeDistributed(convmodel)(inputs)

    # now a model with the two GRUs which move in different directions
    time_dist=Reshape((40,40,40, 3))(time_dist)

    # The next line will crash
    up=CGRU(go_backwards=False, return_sequences=True, name="up", input_shape=[40,40,40,3])(time_dist)
    down=CGRU(go_backwards=True, return_sequences=True, name="down", input_shape=[40,40,40,3])(time_dist)

    # merge the two outputs
    merged_updown=merge([up,down], mode="concat", concat_axis=2)
    reshaped=Reshape((40,40,40,2))(merged_updown)

    # and apply a final convolution to map from 2 features back to 1    
    mergeconv_inputs=Input((40,40,2))
    mergeconv=Convolution2D(1,3,3, activation="sigmoid", border_mode="same")(mergeconv_inputs)
    merge_model=Model(input=mergeconv_inputs, output=mergeconv)

    final_time_dist=TimeDistributed(merge_model)(reshaped)

    output=Reshape((40,40,40,1))(final_time_dist)

    model=Model(input=inputs, output=output)
    print(model.summary())
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
```

The very same code, with the "tf" image layout, runs fine under theano and crashes with tensorflow.

The problem is: `ValueError: Shapes (?, ?, 40, 40) and (40, ?, 40) are not compatible`

Here is the complete error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-295ff1bf414f> in <module>()
     25     # now a model with the two GRUs which move in different directions
     26     time_dist=Reshape((40,40,40, 3))(time_dist)
---> 27     up=CGRU(go_backwards=False, return_sequences=True, name="up", input_shape=[40,40,40,3])(time_dist)
     28     down=CGRU(go_backwards=True, return_sequences=True, name="down", input_shape=[40,40,40,3])(time_dist)
     29 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in __call__(self, x, mask)
    513         if inbound_layers:
    514             # this will call layer.build() if necessary
--> 515             self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
    516             input_added = True
    517 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in add_inbound_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
    571         # creating the node automatically updates self.inbound_nodes
    572         # as well as outbound_nodes on inbound layers.
--> 573         Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
    574 
    575     def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in create_node(cls, outbound_layer, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
    148 
    149         if len(input_tensors) == 1:
--> 150             output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
    151             output_masks = to_list(outbound_layer.compute_mask(input_tensors[0], input_masks[0]))
    152             # TODO: try to auto-infer shape if exception is raised by get_output_shape_for

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.pyc in call(self, x, mask)
    211                                              constants=constants,
    212                                              unroll=self.unroll,
--> 213                                              input_length=input_shape[1])
    214         if self.stateful:
    215             self.updates = []

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in rnn(step_function, inputs, initial_states, go_backwards, mask, constants, unroll, input_length)
   1193             parallel_iterations=32,
   1194             swap_memory=True,
-> 1195             sequence_length=None)
   1196 
   1197         if nb_states > 1:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in _dynamic_rnn_loop(cell, inputs, initial_state, parallel_iterations, swap_memory, sequence_length, dtype)
   1023     shape = _state_size_with_prefix(
   1024         output_size, prefix=[const_time_steps, const_batch_size])
-> 1025     output.set_shape(shape)
   1026 
   1027   final_outputs = nest.pack_sequence_as(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in set_shape(self, shape)
    406         this tensor.
    407     """
--> 408     self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)
    409 
    410   @property

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.pyc in merge_with(self, other)
    568       except ValueError:
    569         raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" %
--> 570                          (self, other))
    571 
    572   def concatenate(self, other):

ValueError: Shapes (?, ?, 40, 40) and (40, ?, 40) are not compatible
```

Comment: FYI, theano *only* uses `NCHW` image format while TF uses `NHWC` format for default. Not sure if is related.

Comment: That is strange, because you can switch image-dim-ordering in the keras.json file. And I can run a model which relies on tf ordering in theano. With the new layer

Comment: I mean a model where the data definitely has the tensorflow layout: samples, timesteps, width, height, features. Explicitly transposed to this layout. I check model.summary, too.

Comment: @Ihk I think Keras can adapt by transposing the rank-4 tensor, however this might lead to some internal coding error causing the issue.

Comment: @Kh40tiK sounds promising, do you have any tips for solving this problem?

Comment: @Ihk Not sure, not a Keras user myself. Maybe running debugger through Keras source helps.